# Is there code scanning tool to tell Django project from a Flask project?

Tags: python, code-analysis, static-analysis, static-code-analysis

I am wondering if there exists some tools that can scan code-base and then give a confident answer to "is this code built from Django, or is this code built from Flask or Pylon?" or 'did this code started from Django framework or Flask framework?'

Thanks,

Comment: How confident do you have to be? Darth Vader's solution (or just something like `grep -r django *`) will cover most cases, and would only be fooled by the tiny number of projects that started as one but mention the other.

Answer (score 2):

Just something I threw together off the top of my head:

```
import glob
import os
import sys

base = None

if sys.version.startswith('2'):
    from __future__ import print_function
    base = raw_input("Enter base dir: ")
else: 
    base = input("Enter base dir: ")

os.chdir(base)

for file in glob.glob("*.py"):
    with open(file, 'r') as current:
        for line in current.readlines()
            if line.startswith("import django"):
                print("%s uses django" % current.name)
            elif line.startswith("import flask"):
                print("%s uses flask" % current.name)
            else:
                print("%s does not use django or flask" % current.name)
```

Comment: this breaks on `import flask #so glad I don't have to type "import django" anymore!`

Comment: @Kevin ermahgerd, so many people must have that comment in their code! In any case, I actually edited it to cover that scenario.

Comment: I'm not saying it'd be common. :)  You could still fail on multiline string literals, but I concede that this is rare enough to not even bother with.